# Android Mobile SDK: Adding/Fetching Contact Image

Tags: connected-apps, sfdcmobilesdk-android

The **PhotoUrl** I get from the API is like this:

> /services/images/photo/0036F000024S6IMQA0

I tried accessing it by adding the API Url:

> https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/images/photo/0036F000024S6IMQA0

It redirects to

> https://ap4.salesforce.com/profilephoto/005/T

and shows the default 45x45 image. How can I access these files using any standard Image Loader like Picasso.

Also, how to add a Contact Image using the API?

I could `add an Account -> get the Id -> Add it as a AccountId field and add the Contact`

This is how I relate a Contact with it's Account. Didn't find a way to add an Image.